# Loading content in div

Tags: php, jquery

I have the 3 php files when the user clicks a form the 2.php file is loaded to see if user  can fill out the form or not if he can a form shows up and after he fills up the form I want the result displayed in the `div id=content` of 1.php

Is calling/opening  the php file with form content in new window better practice than loading it in div.Is loading the div unnecessary hardwork? i think  its better for user to click links and see what he wishes to see in the `div id=content` on the same page.
Is it good practice?

Also i'm facing an issue with loading the form results in the div after i click  submit the form disappears something i'm doing wrong?

here are the 3 files

**1.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Test </title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
        </script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/layout.css"; />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header">
        </div>
        <div id="menu">
            <a href="#" id="l1"> Form </a>
        </div>  
        <div id="content">
        </div>  
        <div id="footer">
        </div>
    </body>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#l1').click(function(){
                $('#content').load('2.php');
            });
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

**2.php**

```
<?php
//code here that checks if user can fill form

echo'<script>$("#content").load("3.php");</script>';

// if user cannot
echo "You have already filled";
?>
```

**3.php**

```
<?php
    //check for user session and form_status using $_SESSION 
    if( isset($_POST['submit']) ){
        $form_value=array();
        foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
            $form_value[$key]=htmlspecialchars(trim($value),ENT_QUOTES);
            echo "{$form_value[$key]}<br/>";
        }

    }
?>
    <form method="post" name="stud_det" id="stud_det" action="" >
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Name :</td><td><input type="text" name="name" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Register Number :</td><td><input type="text" name="regno"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Date of Birth :</td><td><input type="text" name="dob"/></td> 
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" style="font-size:16px;"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>

<script>
    $("#stud_det").submit(function(){
            $.ajax({
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                type: $(this).attr("post"),
                url: $(this).attr("3.php");
                success: function(response){
                    $("#content").html(response);
                }
            });
            return true;
        });
</script>
```

**layout.css**

```
#menu{
    position:absolute;
    top:10%;
    bottom:10%;
    left:0;
    right:90%;
    background-color:#7c7;
    font-size:18px;
}
#header{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:90%;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    background-color:#ff0;
}
#footer{
    position:absolute;
    top:90%;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    background-color:#fcf;
}
#content{
    position:absolute;
    top:10%;
    bottom:10%;
    left:10%;
    right:0;
    background-color:#ccc;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:18px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loading content into the current page without reloading is often more flexible, so it's common practice.

For the last problem, in your `.submit()` function, change `return true` to `return false`. Returning false tells the browser not to run the default action of the submit button, which is to do a normal form submission that reloads the page.

Other errors I found when running your code:

You have an unwanted `;` here:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/layout.css"; />
```

Your AJAX has:

```
            type: $(this).attr("post"),
            url: $(this).attr("3.php");
```

Those are wrong, it should be:

```
            type: $(this).attr("method"),
            url: "3.php",
```

Another issue is that when you use `$(this).serialize()`, it doesn't include the `submit` button in the data. So when `3.php` does `if(isset($_POST['submit']))`, it doesn't succeed. I suggest you check whether one of the input fields is set instead.

So with all the fixes, `3.php` now looks like:

```
<?php
    //check for user session and form_status using $_SESSION 
    if( isset($_POST['name']) ){
        $form_value=array();
        foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
            $form_value[$key]=htmlspecialchars(trim($value),ENT_QUOTES);
            echo "{$form_value[$key]}<br/>";
        }

    }
?>
    <form method="post" name="stud_det" id="stud_det" action="" >
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Name :</td><td><input type="text" name="name" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Register Number :</td><td><input type="text" name="regno"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Date of Birth :</td><td><input type="text" name="dob"/></td> 
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" style="font-size:16px;"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>

<script>
    $("#stud_det").submit(function(){
            $.ajax({
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                type: $(this).attr("method"),
                url: "3.php",
                success: function(response){
                    $("#content").html(response);
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
//@ sourceURL=dynamicScript.js
</script>
```

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20857200/form-result-in-same-page) I posted a question related to loading result in div yester.

Comment: return true/false both make form disappear

Comment: I don't think the absolute positioning of `#content` matters, because it doesn't change when you submit the form.

Comment: it works for just 2 files if i open 2.php and 3.php loads fine

Comment: Thanks will make changes

Comment: yes it works after I remove isset($_POST['submit']) is there any way to include submit?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6397067/why-serialize-does-not-include-submit-button-name